# How do I create a date picker in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, datepicker, firemonkey

Is there any standard component for selecting a date in the [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python)?

I'm looking for some kind of Date Picker component. Currently what I'm doing is making a couple of `SpinBox` components and then using them to enter a Date, this is my UI:

[image: Year, Month, Day Python GUI]

But what I actually want is just one component for selecting a date instead of three SpinBox components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Calendar` and `DateEdit` component that you can use:

```
self.myCalendar = Calendar(self)
self.myCalendar.Parent = self
self.myCalendar.Align = "MostTop"
self.myCalendar.Margins.Top = 20
self.myCalendar.Margins.Right = 20
self.myCalendar.Margins.Bottom = 20
self.myCalendar.Margins.Left = 20

self.myDateEdit = DateEdit(self)
self.myDateEdit.Parent = self
self.myDateEdit.Align = "Top"
self.myDateEdit.Margins.Right = 20
self.myDateEdit.Margins.Bottom = 20
self.myDateEdit.Margins.Left = 20
```

This will look like the following screenshot:
[image: Calendar and DateEdit components in Python FMX GUI App]